# Looking for the best practice to write SQL in Oracle when same subquery is used twice

Tags: oracle

I'm writing a SQL in Oracle. In the SQL, I have the same subquery used twice. I'm trying to find the best way for replacing such common subquery or queries that get reused.

I was thinking to create a view for the subquery but I'm not allowed to do so. Global temporary tables could be other solution but I came to know that such tables aren't really for creating and dropping on the fly.

Comment: :I think its better to create a `procedure` and used that query inside that proc ,and called that proc everytime when you need the result of that query .Considering that you dint have access to  create view

Comment: @Guarav: I disagree. If you can do it in SQL, then you should. Why complicate the query with a procedure (which you can't even use from SQL, you have to use PL/SQL), that's likely going to negatively impact performance? Better to use the WITH clause as Jeffery Kemp states, or even repeat the subquery.

Comment: @DCookie:Thanks for correcting me Sir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a view or a global temporary table, but it's often better to use a WITH clause, e.g.:

```
WITH q AS
  (SELECT something FROM mytable)
SELECT something FROM q
UNION ALL
SELECT something+1 FROM q;
```